# Using jQuery to fire an event on content just added by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery script which is triggered by an onClick event ( through $(".addContent").click(function(){ )  and which updates the page, adding an input text tag.

I am subsequently trying to trigger another script using an onChange event ( through $(".guestInput").change(function(){ ) on the input text tag which was just added, once the viewer makes a change.  It doesn't work.

I have tried adding the input text tag as static html, and the subsequent onChange event fires successfully, but not when I add the field through jQuery.

Hope this is clear.

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use live() for DOM elements added after the initial page load.

so `.click(function() { do_something; });`

would now be `.live("click", function() { do_something; });`

see: http://api.jquery.com/live/

> **Description:** Attach an event handler for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now **and in the future**.

Comment: David, Thank You!  I just wish I'd asked you last night.

Comment: No problem man! This one took about 2 days out of my learning schedule when I first started messing with ajax/jquery. Seems so obvious now...